# Translate Filter button layered nav sidebar Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, inline-translations, js-translation

could anyone tell me how can I translate the value "FILTER" for button price in layered navigation?

I have a multilingual site all translated except that label, always appear in English as you can see in the image below.

I tired everything, the inline translation doesn't work, the tranlsate.csv doesn't work too and I can't find the right .phtml file or a js file.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: enable template path hints from admin it will display path of the file

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have well the translation function in the file of the translated word `<?php echo $this->__('Filter')?>`
2. if you can't translate it, you can simply use the [inline](http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/) translation,the translation will be stored in database `core_translate` table (the hight priority one).

Comment: The inline translation for that button doesn't work, rhe translations file are ok, I think I need to find the file in wich the input button value is declarated but I can't find that file

Comment: You have to enable the path hints templates to find your file look this: http://support.magerewards.com/article/1534-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints